# How to access Steaming Assets folder?

Tags: android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So in my project I have an image object that loads various different sprites throughout the game. In order to implement this, I have a folder with a bunch of .pngs that the game accesses. In order for this to work in a standalone build I put these images in the following path:

```
StreamingAssets/Question Images
```

However, in Android I am getting an error because, as the manual says:

"On Android, the files are contained within a compressed .jar file (which is essentially the same format as standard zip-compressed files). This means that if you do not use Unity’s WWW class to retrieve the file, you need to use additional software to see inside the .jar archive and obtain the file.

The thing is I have no idea how to go about implementing this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html)

> It is **not possible** to access the `StreamingAssets` folder on WebGL and **Android** platforms. No file access is available on WebGL. Android uses a compressed .apk file. These platforms return a URL. Use the [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) class to access the Assets.

Example using [`UnityWebRequestTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTexture.html)

```
private void Start() 
{
    StartCoroutine(GetTexture());
}

private IEnumerator GetTexture() 
{
    // in general I would always avoid to have spaces in file-paths
    var path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "QuestionImages", "exampleImage.png");

    using(var www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(path))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) 
        {
            Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Unable to load texture due to {0} - {1}", www.responseCode, www.error);
        }
        else 
        {
            Texture myTexture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)www.downloadHandler).texture;
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warrenty but I hope the idea gets clear.*